# Checkboxes and trying to save the state of all checkboxes for the user when they return

Tags: javascript, checkbox, local-storage

```
function getFormState() {
    var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].elements;
    if (fields.length === 0) {
        return;
    };
    for (var i = 0; i <= fields.length - 1; i++) {
        var name = fields[i].getAttribute('name');
        if (document.getElementByTagName('name').checked === true) {
            localStorage.setItem('name', "true");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('name', "false");
        }
    }
}

function fillFormState() {
    var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].elements;
    if (fields.length === 0) {
        return;
    };
    for (var i = 0; i <= fields.length - 1; i++) {
        var name = fields[i].getAttribute('name');
        getStatus = localStorage.getItem('name'); {
            if (getStatus === "true") {
                console.log("its checked");
                document.getElementByTagName("name").setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                console.log("its not checked");
            }
        }
    }
} // run the below functions when the web page is loadedwindow.onload = function () {
// check if HTML5 localStorage is supported by the browser
if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    // get the form state
    getFormState();
    // save the state of the form each X seconds (customizable)
    setInterval('fillFormState()', 1 * 1000);

}
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work. And Im trying to figure out why. Im not very experienced with javascript so it might be quite obvious. Sorry for that. Im trying.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the way in which the code doesn't work? Are there errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `localStorage` is never being set because of this loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= fields.length - 1; i++) {
    var name = fields[i].getAttribute('name');
    if (document.getElementByTagName('name').checked === true) {
        localStorage.setItem('name', "true");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('name', "false");
    }
}
```

There is no `document.getElementByTagName`, and you are also searching for `"name"` instead of your variable `name`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= fields.length - 1; i++) {
    var name = fields[i].getAttribute('name');
    if (fields[i].checked === true) { //Check the current field
        localStorage.setItem(name, "true"); //Set the actual name, not "name"
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(name, "false");
    }
}
```